# Count number of columns in CSV files and rename if less than 11 columns

Tags: awk, files, rename, csv

I need to count the number of columns in CSV files. If less than 11, rename the file appending the `.bad` suffix.  I tried this but it's short of what I need:

```
head -1 myfile.csv | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

I need to do it for all files in a directory.

Comment: You should give ["Data Science at the Command Line"](http://datascienceatthecommandline.com/) a look. The post provides some tools for handling csv-files from the command line (they're Python based command line programs).

Answer (score 5):

```
for file in *.csv; do
    cols=$( awk -F, 'NR == 1 {print NF; exit}' "$file" )
    if [[ "$cols" -lt 11 ]]; then
        mv -v "$file" "$file.bad"
    fi
done
```

or, with bash without awk

```
for file in *.csv; do
    IFS=, read -ra fields <"$file"
    if [[ "${#fields[@]}" -lt 11 ]]; then
        mv -v "$file" "$file.bad"
    fi
done
```

Comment: good one, NR==1 not needed as exit is there..

Answer (score 4):

Another short **`awk`** approach:

```
for f in *.csv; do 
    awk -F, '{ exit (NF < 11? 0:1) }' "$f" && mv "$f" "${f}.bad"
done
```

---

- `NF < 11?` - if number of fields `NF` is less than **11**
- the statement `mv "$f" "${f}.bad"` will be executed only if preceded `awk` statement returned `exit 0` (as a positive evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

`perl` has [rename](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) built-in function (with caveats, so check the documentation)

```
perl -F, -ane '$f=$ARGV; $c=$#F+1; close ARGV; rename $f,"$f.bad" if $c<11' *.csv
```

- `-F,` use `,` as field separator, see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for details on other options
- `$f=$ARGV` save filename
- `$c=$#F+1` get number of columns
- `close ARGV` close the file
- `rename $f,"$f.bad" if $c<11` rename if number of columns is less than 11